# Image URL validation in C#

Tags: c#, validation, browser, hyperlink

How can i check if my [image](http://dl.cat-verlag.de/catw1/news-ppw-bilder/10149341.jpg) link is valid for both IE and FF? For example this link works just in FF, no image is displayed in IE browser. I checked the image and the color space is RGB. So image space problem is excluded.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, visit the target of the link and see if you connect correctly. Perhaps you mean something different. It's difficult to tell from the wording of your question.

Comment: Let's say that i have a method : ValidateLink and 2 paramters: link and browser. So i want to test if is my link is valid if i access it from FF or IE: ValidateLink("http://www.google.com", "FireFox") and ValidateLink("http://www.google.com", "InternetExplorer").

Comment: What's an example image URL that does *not* work in IE but *does* in FireFox?

Comment: Is it the URL or the image format that is the problem? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support

Comment: For example i have this image url :http://dl.cat-verlag.de/catw1/news-ppw-bilder/10149341.jpg witch works in FF but not in IE.

Comment: The reason you can't see this image in IE is that it's saved as CMYK instead of RGB. You might want to reword your question title to reflect this.

Comment: If you use the `ColorConvertedBitmap` etc classes from WPF, you can convert between CMYK and RGB. But I'm not sure this is what you're asking.

Comment: If i save the image and rename it will work in IE too. But how can i find if loads in IE?

Comment: @Andrei I thought your problem was that some of your JPEG images were CMYK and hence didn't work in IE?

Comment: No. I tested an my image is RGB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get a copy of fiddler to see the differences in response for each of the browsers. You may find that the headers are wrong and FF is correcting but IE is not.

http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Hope this helps

Comment: ok, fiddler it's a tool, but how this can be made with c#? I think this it will really help Andrei.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a class that will let you validate any kind of URI and will support multi-threaded validation of collection of URIs

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace UrlValidation
{
    public class UrlValidator
    {
        internal static readonly Hashtable URLVerifications = new Hashtable();
        internal readonly List<ManualResetEvent> Handles = new List<ManualResetEvent>();

        internal void ValidateUrls()
        {
            var urlsToValidate = new[] { "http://www.ok12376876.com", "http//:www.ok.com", "http://www.ok.com", "http://cnn.com" };
            URLVerifications.Clear();
            foreach (var url in urlsToValidate)
                CheckUrl(url);
            if (Handles.Count > 0)
                WaitHandle.WaitAll(Handles.ToArray());

            foreach (DictionaryEntry verification in URLVerifications)
                Console.WriteLine(verification.Value);
        }

        internal class RequestState
        {
            public WebRequest Request;
            public WebResponse Response;
            public ManualResetEvent Handle;
        }

        private void CheckUrl(string url)
        {
            var hashCode = url.GetHashCode();
            var evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
            Handles.Add(evt);

            if (!Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(url, UriKind.Absolute))
            {
                URLVerifications[hashCode] = "Invalid URL.";
                evt.Set();
                return;
            }

            if (!URLVerifications.ContainsKey(hashCode))
                URLVerifications.Add(hashCode, null);
            // Create a new webrequest to the mentioned URL.   
            var wreq = WebRequest.Create(url);
            wreq.Timeout = 5000; // 5 seconds timeout per thread (ignored for async calls)
            var state = new RequestState{ Request = wreq, Handle = evt };
            // Start the Asynchronous call for response.
            var asyncResult = wreq.BeginGetResponse(RespCallback, state);
            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle, TimeoutCallback, state, 5000, true);
        }

        private static void TimeoutCallback(object state, bool timedOut)
        {
            var reqState = (RequestState)state;
            if (timedOut)
            {
                var hashCode = reqState.Request.RequestUri.OriginalString.GetHashCode();
                URLVerifications[hashCode] = "Request timed out.";
                if (reqState.Request != null)
                    reqState.Request.Abort();
            }
        }

        private static void RespCallback(IAsyncResult asynchronousResult)
        {
            ManualResetEvent evt = null;
            int hashCode = 0;
            try
            {
                var reqState = (RequestState)asynchronousResult.AsyncState;
                hashCode = reqState.Request.RequestUri.OriginalString.GetHashCode();
                evt = reqState.Handle;
                reqState.Response = reqState.Request.EndGetResponse(asynchronousResult);
                var resp = ((HttpWebResponse)reqState.Response).StatusCode;
                URLVerifications[hashCode] = resp.ToString();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                if (hashCode != 0 && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)URLVerifications[hashCode]))
                    URLVerifications[hashCode] = e.Response == null ? e.Status.ToString() : (int)((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode + ": " + ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode;
            }
            finally
            {
                if (evt != null)
                    evt.Set();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps