# how to wait for all background threads to finish (in C#)?

Tags: c#, multithreading

how to make the foreground thread wait for all background (child) threads to finish in C#? I need to get list of pending jobs from the queue (database), start a new thread to execute each of them and finally wait for all the child threads to finish. how to do that in C#? Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Spawn Multiple Threads for work then wait until all finished](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2528907/c-spawn-multiple-threads-for-work-then-wait-until-all-finished)

Comment: have u try [EventWaitHandle();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.eventwaithandle.aspx)

Comment: thanks for all the quick replies to my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider using ThreadPool.  Most of what you want is already done.  There is an [example from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as%28VS.80%29.aspx) which does pretty much your entire task.  Replace "fibonacci" with "database task" and it sounds like your problem.

Comment: I read this article few minutes back and was about to reply saying that is the solution I was looking for. thanks for the reply.

Comment: Last copy of above [example from Microsoft](https://web.archive.org/web/20150124003832/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3dasc8as(VS.80).aspx) before they took the documentation offline in 2015. The example has been moved into the docs for [ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool.queueuserworkitem#system-threading-threadpool-queueuserworkitem(system-threading-waitcallback-system-object)) in newer versions

Answer (score 7):

You could store each launched thread in an array. Then when you need to wait for them all, call Join method on each thread in an array in a loop.

```
Thread child = new Thread(...);
Threads.Add(child);
child.Start()

...

foreach(Thread t in Threads)
{
   t.Join();
}
```

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think thread.Join method is good for a single thread or very few fixed number of threads. for multiple threads, I think there is a WaitAll method, but I couldn't find a good code example for it.

Comment: @RKP: Waiting fo all threads to finish is the same as to wait for them in turn, isn't it? There is a winapi function WaitForMultipleObjects, but it's not C#, though you can use it, but I see no point.

Answer (score 1):

This is incomplete code, but `ManualResetEvent` works for you

```
var waitEvents = new List<ManualResetEvent>();
foreach (var action in actions)
{
    var evt = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    waitEvents.Add(evt);
    ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle, TimeoutCallback, state, 5000, true);
}

if (waitEvents.Count > 0)
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(waitEvents.ToArray());
```

Comment: Thanks, but where the new thread for each action is started here in this code? is "5000" a timeout setting?

Comment: Look here for entire code, I just copied a bit from one of my previous answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915017/image-url-validation-in-c/3915440#3915440

Comment: And yes, 5000 was a timeout setting

Answer (score 1):

Using dynamic data you can pass your object and the WaitHandle (ActionResetEvent) that lets you wait for all the background threads to finish without declaring an extra class:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<AutoResetEvent> areList = new List<AutoResetEvent>();
    foreach (MyObject o in ListOfMyObjects)
    {
        AutoResetEvent are = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        areList.Add(are);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWork, new { o, are });
    };

    Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}", DateTime.Now);
    WaitHandle.WaitAll(areList.ToArray());
    Console.WriteLine("Time: {0}", DateTime.Now);
    Console.ReadKey();
}

static void DoWork(object state)
{
    dynamic o = state;
    MyObject myObject = (MyObject)o.o;
    AutoResetEvent are = (AutoResetEvent)o.are;

    myObject.Execute();
    are.Set();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a structure to keep track of your worker threads

```
private struct WorkerThreadElement
{
    public IAsyncResult WorkerThreadResult;
    public AsyncActionExecution WorkerThread;
}
```

You also need to keep track the total number of threads expected to be created and the number of threads that have currently completed

```
private int _TotalThreads = 0;
private int _ThreadsHandled = 0;
private List<WorkerThreadElement> _WorkerThreadElements = new List<WorkerThreadElement>();
```

Then create an autoreset handle in order to wait for thread completion.

```
// The wait handle thread construct to signal the completion of this process
private EventWaitHandle _CompletedHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);
```

You also need a delegate to create new threads - There are multiple ways of doing this but i have chosen a simple delegate for the sake of this example

```
// Delegate to asynchronously invoke an action
private delegate void AsyncActionExecution();
```

Lets asume that the Invoke method is the entrance point that will create all threads and wait for their execution. So we have:

```
public void Invoke()
{ 
    _TotalThreads = N; /* Change with the total number of threads expected */

    foreach (Object o in objects) 
    {
        this.InvokeOneThread();
    }             

    // Wait until execution has been completed
    _CompletedHandle.WaitOne();

    // Collect any exceptions thrown and bubble them up
    foreach (WorkerThreadElement workerThreadElement in _WorkerThreadElements)
    {
        workerThreadElement.WorkerThread.EndInvoke(workerThreadElement.WorkerThreadResult);
    }
}
```

InvokeOneThread is the method used to create a single thread for one operation. Here we need to create a worker thread element and invoke the actual thread.

```
 private void InvokeOneThread()
 {
     WorkerThreadElement threadElement = new WorkerThreadElement();
     threadElement.WorkerThread = new AsyncActionExecution();
     threadElement.WorkerThreadResult = threadElement.WorkerThread.BeginInvoke(actionParameters, InvokationCompleted, null);

     _WorkerThreadElements.Add(threadElement);
 }
```

Callback from thread completion

```
private object _RowLocker = new object();

/// <summary>
/// Increment the number of rows that have been fully processed
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ar"></param>
private void InvokationCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    lock (_RowLocker) 
    {
        _RowsHandled++; 
    }

    if (_TotalThreads == _ThreadsHandled) 
        _CompletedHandle.Set();
}
```

Done